# GitHub actions pull error Unothorized for docker registry

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-registry, jib

I am trying to implement CI to my API by using GitHub actions, but when I add my stuff to GitHub, the maven test and building fail ([the actions on GitHub and the one that fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym19Q.png)).

More specifically, the error comes from jib which is not authorized to do actions on my docker registry which by the way, is public ([screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W7ss.png))

It seems like the GitHub action does not log in with the docker information, I have the same error when I execute an "mvn clean package" without using "docker login" before.

I tried to add login credentials to github with a login step to the actions but it did not change the error.

Here is my CI.yml file

```
name: CI - Build Backend

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - backend/**
```

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14.1
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: customer
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options:
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./backend
```

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
    with:
      distribution: 'temurin'
      java-version: '17'
      cache: 'maven'
  - name: Login to Docker Hub
    uses: docker/login-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
  - name: Build and run Unit/Integration Tests with Maven
    run: mvn -ntp -B verify
```

here is also my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
```

```
<groupId>org.amigoscode</groupId>
<artifactId>amigoscode-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<organization>
    <name>amigoscode</name>
    <url>https://amigoscode.com</url>
</organization>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <docker.username>armine27</docker.username>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--server.port=${tomcat.http.port}</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <test.server.port>${tomcat.http.port}</test.server.port>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>reserve-tomcat-port</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <portNames>
                            <portName>tomcat.http.port</portName>
                        </portNames>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <from>
                    <image>eclipse-temurin:17</image>
                    <platforms>
                        <platform>
                            <architecture>arm64</architecture>
                            <os>linux</os>
                        </platform>
                        <platform>
                            <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                            <os>linux</os>
                        </platform>
                    </platforms>
                </from>
                <to>
                    <image>docker.io/armine27/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                    </tags>
                </to>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Apparently, from the logs, it looks like that your registry address is different i.e. `registry-1.docker.io` than the standard Docker Hub one which is used if you omit `registry` input parameter. See https://github.com/docker/login-action#inputs. Try adding `registry: registry-1.docker.io` and test again. It's better to put the registry address in a secret too.